# Acumatica Field Services - Linking the CSAnswer information to the FSAppointment Table

Tags: service, attributes, field, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I've currently created four Attributes on the Field Services Appointment (FS300200) form to show manually entered start and finish kilometres. This field will then flow into Forms and be the basis of reports throughout the system.

[FieldServicesAppointment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht3vD.png)

My problem is, how do I link the *CSAnswers* to the *FSAppointment* Table. There doesn't seem to be a logical join. The last time I used this area the *RefNoteID* and *Attribute* provided the link. I know that this changed so that most major tables show attributes e.g. STYLE_Attribute. Unfortunately this isn't the case for *FSAppointments, FSAppointmentDets* (my next guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but I just checked this with 2020R1 and FSAppointment.NoteID joined correctly to CSAnswers.REfNoteID

Comment: That is the correct join Patrick. We realised a little later this was the case. Not enough sleep or coffee in this case.